# load div on page load then replace content w/ onclick

Tags: jquery, html, load, onclick

I have sidebar navigation links that load content into an adjacent div (with jquery load()).

The content is replaced with each new click on a link.

I need to have content loaded by default into the div when the page loads and then have that default content stripped out to be replaced with the load() function.

At this point the page loads and will always keep the initial content, and replaces the other additional divs when each is activated by clicking the link.

I want you to see something when you come to the page in that target div, but then to have it replaced with new content from those sidebar links...

Comment: hmm as far as replacing the default content.. not much. I'm a novice at JS, but have looked through the stack and not seen an answer. I'm trying using a class of hidden and then activating that when the links are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger the click event on the anchor by calling trigger() method in jQuery on load.

Comment: So the trigger() method would hide the default content?

Comment: It fires the click event and in the event handling u can override or hide the content